# Combine Two Images and Make One Semi-Transparent / Opaque in The GIMP

Tags: gimp

I have two existing images that are identical in size and I would like to combine them, so that I can see a "faded" version of one image on top of the other.

In other words, I want to make "Image A" semi-transparent / opaque and place it on top of "Image B", so that I can see "Image B" *and* see a faded version of "Image A" (over the top of "Image B").

I am using The GIMP 2.10.30.

Comment: Is "The GIMP" correct? should it not just be "GIMP" ?

Comment: It's "GIMP", though it *should* be "The GIMP" is you ask me, because the acronym stands for "GNU Image Manipulation Program"... Having used "GIMP" since Day One and knowing its acronym since that time, I write "The GIMP" out of habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open bottom image in Gimp
- Use `File > Open as layers` to load the second image above the first one
- In the `Layers` list (Ctr-L if you don't see it), use the "Opacity" slider at the top of the list to set opacity to taste (slider applies to layer selected in the list below)

Comment: Worked a charm... Thank you good sir!